# Ultegra 6600 compatible chainrings

Tags: chainring, compatibility

I am looking to replace the chainrings on my bike, which has 10-speed Ultegra 6600 double (it's the "ice grey" SL version, so I think technically it's 6601-G).

Amazingly, there are still some 6601-G inner chainrings available, and I understand that TA Specialites' 130 PCD Alize would be compatible too.

For the outer, no original Shimano chainrings seem to be available (I am in the UK), and the Alize outer chainring in 53T is out of stock everywhere I have looked.

What are in stock are Shimano 105 FC-5700 chainrings - are these compatible with Ultegra 6600/SL?  I realise it might be what Shimano would call a "B" match ("parts are usable, but differ in materials, appearance, finish & size") - of course, the TA rings would be this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ultegra 6600 series is old enough to use standard 130mm 5-bolt chainrings, so any 10-11 speed compatible chainring with correct bolt pattern can be used. These are available from TA, Stronglight, SRAM, FSA and others.

The Shimano "A" and "B" rings are intended to match with 42- and 39-tooth inner chainrings. Other manufacturers don't have this distinction, and I haven't read about any problems from using a "mismatched" outer ring.